# How to get dt element text using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a below html code

```
 <dl>
<dt><label>test</label></dt>
<dd><input id="someid" type="checkbox" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="product-custom-option"></dd>
<dt><label>test</label></dt>
<dd><input id="someid" type="checkbox" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="product-custom-option"></dd>
<dt><label>test</label></dt>
<dd><input id="someid" type="checkbox" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="product-custom-option"></dd>
<dt><label>test</label></dt>
<dd><input id="someid" type="checkbox" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" class="product-custom-option"></dd>
</dl>

<script>
reloadPrice : function() {
            var config = this.config;
            var skipIds = [];
            $$('body .product-custom-option').each(function(element){
                //todo
                });
</script>
```

I want to get dt->label element text in loop.there is function name 'reloadprice' in my prototype function.it run on change event.so how can i get label text using prototype.
any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing `var opConfig = {` and `} };`

Answer (score 0):

Prototype extends `DOM`, so try this:

```
  $$('.product-custom-option').each(function(element){
      //element return DOM node which is extended by prototype
      console.log(element.up().previous().down().innerHTML);
  });
```

I created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83YZh/1/), all works fine.

Comment: Remember, a DL can have multiple DT or DD elements in a row, so you may want to qualify the `previous()` to `previous('dt')` so you aren't ambiguous. This is valid: `<dl><dt>Pears</dt><dd>Bosc</dd><dd>Golden</dd><dt>Apples>/dt><dd>Rome</dd><dd>Pippin</dd></dl>`

Comment: @pinal modified your code with little `console.log(element.up().previous().down().innerHTML);` changes and it work on body onload only not on change event it throw error on change event like `TypeError: element.up(...).previous(...) is undefined`

Comment: Thanks for comments, add console and move all to function.